# Installing NFS module on a dedicated server

Tags: linux, redhat, nfs

I've got a dedicated server which does not have the NFS module installed on it. How can I install it?

It was not listed in /proc/filesystems

```
root@server [~]# cat /proc/filesystems | grep 'nfs'
```

And I wasn’t able to install it as a module

```
root@server [~]# insmod nfs
insmod: can't read 'nfs': No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using RHEL/CentOS 5 and you want to setup an NFS *CLIENT* in that box:

1. yum install nfs-utils
2. service portmap start (or bounce the server)

and you are ready to go.

Assuming you are using RHEL/CentOS 5 and you want to setup an NFS *SERVER* in that box:

1. yum install nfs-utils
2. chkconfig nfs on (to activate the service when booting)
3. service portmap start
4. service nfs start

the last 2 are not required if you reboot the server.
You don't need to load modules manually for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Unless it's acquired some sort of higher level metadata since the last time I looked, `insmod` needs the whole path to the module file.  Try looking for files named `*nfs*.o`.

Answer (score 0):

Try `modprobe` instead. But it should be loaded on demand once you try to actually mount a NFS filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

Try 'modprobe nfs'